# How to access folder in tomcat server using relative path of it?

Tags: java, javascript, tomcat, war

I have one folder which has some PDF files which is used by my application, but when I include this folder in  my war file , the size of war file increase to GBzz , so I thought of keeping this folder in some server location , build and deploy the war without the folder which will have the relative path of this folder , can any one help me on this? I am not sure how to do configuration for this to read the folder ?I am using tomcat server.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way starting from Tomcat 7 is to configure alias paths i.e. paths on the disk that will be aliased in Tomcat. Check [this section in the guide](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/context.html#Standard_Implementation) for **aliases** attribute.
You want something like this in your server.xml:

```
<Context docBase="AppName" path="/appname" aliases="/pathPdf=c:\pdfs"/>
```

In case you're on an older Tomcat, your best bet is to setup a servlet that will serve files from the desired external location.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, could you please let me know how this thing can work on stage or testing server  because on my local server I can manage but I am facing this issue when I deploying on higher env. I might be asking dump question but I am quiet new to this , please guide me ?

Comment: I don't see what the difference between those environments would be?? I'm not sure if Tomcat would be able to resolve a network path for example, but any local disk path should be fine, on both Windows and *nix. What problem are you having?